# Aptana PHP editor the (") after { would be used verbally only

Tags: eclipse, drupal, aptana

Sorry if the title is confusing

In Eclipse Aptana PHP Editor, if I insert this line:

```
$staff = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT person_in_charge_person_id FROM {".TABLE."}")->fetchCol();
```

The '{"' would be seen as plan text, instead of the end of " pair, by the Aptana Editor.

How to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved on Aptana Studio 3.1 stream. See http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3546

If you want to update to the bleeding-edge of the Studio, you can do so by following the instructions at http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/ and choose the `nightly` builds.

I'll also suggest that if you choose to do so, have an second, stable, Studio installation that you can use in case the nightly breaks.

Cheers